# 960 Grid aligns left in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, 960.gs

I'm using the [960.gs](http://960.gs) CSS framework on a site and have hit problems almost instantly with IE (7, though I assume 6 is no better).

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="design/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="design/960.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="design/text.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container_12">abc</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Given this HTML above (the CSS is just the files bundled with 960), Firefox and Chrome centre the grid, whereas IE pushes it to the left.

I've used 960 before without any issues, so I think I must just be doing something really stupid. Can anyone help?

Comment: If possible, please change the title of this question to - "960 Degree Grid aligns left in Internet Explorer"

this could help others find this resolved question easily... cheers!

Comment: @Pushpinder - it's called '960.gs (for grid-system), and if you search for "960gs aligns left in Internet Explorer" this is the third result already.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to include a DOCTYPE at the beginning of your HTML, otherwise the CSS won't come out right in IE.  You can use the one from the demo file that came with the 960 package.

Comment: Thanks! `<!DOCTYPE html>` was all it took. Bizarre, but true.

Comment: f****** IE. This one drove me crazy. Thanks for the hint :-D

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that there can not be anything in front of the DOCTYPE-tag.

For example, the default Netbeans HTML-template has a few lines of HTML comments before DOCTYPE, so be sure to delete that in order to get 960.gs to work.